# Can I change my ship color?

Tags: starbound

When I upgraded my ship it was half green and half beige, and I don't know how to change that.

[image: Multi-colored ship]

Comment: @DropTableUsers by changing the title you've completely altered the question and made existing answers invalid - I don't know about gaming.se specifically, but that would be strongly frowned upon on Stack Overflow

Comment: Yea i was wondering too because i looked here again because it seemed like a question in hasn't looked at yet

Answer (score 73):

Your ship is not bugged. The novakid race has a train-like ship, with different color "wagons".
This is what the final upgrade looks like: [image: Multiple interlocked sections of ship painted different colours]

Comment: @Yacuty You should mark this answer as accepted (click the big tick on the left near the up/down & score area) if it's the correct answer.